# How do put the xml of menu into the xml file of NavigationView?

Tags: android, xml, android-navigationview

I know I can define the context of xml like it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

which

```
activity_main_drawer.xml
```

is the context of menu to show when I press the hamburger button at tool bar. However, I want the context inside activity_main_drawe.xml to be defined at the same xml as in NavigationView, I tried:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"><TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="abc"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

but the menu is not showing. is there any syntax to do this?